# systemd: finish the execution of custom shell script before starting nginx

Tags: debian, systemd, services, nginx, init-script

Using Debian 9 stable, I want to start a custom shell script before starting NGINX processes and shorewall firewall:

- Do some init work
- Mount a directory (overlayfs) to overlay `/etc` with NGINX configuration, shorewall configuration and `/etc/hosts`
- The script also ends with `sync`, not sure if it's a good idea

> systemctl list-dependencies
>   default.target
>   ● ├─display-manager.service
>   ● ├─systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
>   ● └─multi-user.target
>   ●   ├─console-setup.service
>   ●   ├─cron.service
>   ●   ├─dbus.service
>   ●   ├─dropbear.service
>   ●   ├─myservice.service   <-- My service (link created with systemctl enable)
>   ●   ├─networking.service
>   ●   ├─nginx.service       <-- To be executed after myservice
>   [...]
>   ●   ├─basic.target
>   ●   │ ├─-.mount
>   ●   │ ├─myservice.service <-- My service (link created with systemctl enable)
>   ●   │ ├─shorewall.service  <-- To be executed after myservice

### myservice.service ATTEMPT 1

> [Unit]
>   Description=My startup service
>   Requires=shorewall.service nginx.service
>   Before=shorewall.service nginx.service
>   
>   [Service]
>   RemainAfterExit=yes
>   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice start
>   ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/myservice stop
>   
>   [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target
>   WantedBy=basic.target

The logs:

> journalctl
>   [...]
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev nginx[448]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "server-dev.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:33
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev nginx[448]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed <== NGINX: BAD
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev server[423]: DO: server start DONE <== END OF SCRIPT myservice
>   Oct 12 11:31:43 server-dev shorewall[449]: Compiling using Shorewall 5.0.15.6... <== SHOREWALL: GOOD
>   Oct 12 11:31:44 server-dev shorewall[449]: Processing /etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf...
>   Oct 12 11:31:44 server-dev shorewall[449]: Loading Modules...

Shorewall is systematically started correctly, after the execution of myservice.
Nginx is most of the time started during the execution of myservice,
before `/etc` is correctly overlayed (overlaid?),
and therefore it fails to initialize properly.

### myservice.service ATTEMPT 2

I also tried to change the

> [Install]
>   WantedBy=default.target

And change

> [Unit]
>   Before=multi-user.target

It also does not work.

How can I ensure
that nginx and shorewall start after the execution of myservice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify the type of your systemd service, it defaults to `Type=simple`. This means the service is considered started at the moment its main service process has been forked off (at which point it isn't even executing the `ExecStart` command yet). You probably want to use `Type=oneshot` instead, which waits for the `ExecStart` command to exit before considering the service started. See `man systemd.service` for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ExecStartPre=` option in a drop-in snippet configuration to add the option to Nginx service unit instead of using separate ones (or add `Requires=shorewall.service` to the nginx service unit, though I advise against that).

Use the command `sudo systemctl edit nginx.service` (it creates directory in `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d` with a drop-in snippet config).

Type:

```
[Unit]
Requires=shorewall.service
After=shorewall.service
```

Or:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/your_script
```

This will always execute your script prior to starting nginx service unit.
You should add (since it's a shell script and redirections are not supported by default) `IgnoreSIGPIPE=no` to the service section or Systemd will ignore redirections, pipes and signals otherwise.

For: Mount a directory (overlayfs) to overlay `/etc` with NGINX configuration, shorewall configuration and /etc/hosts.

Add to the service section:

```
TemporaryFileSystem=/etc:ro,nodev,noexec,nosuid
```

This mounts a blank tmpfs mount point on top of the `/etc` directory.  You will need to bind mount (using `BindReadOnlyPaths=`, `BindPaths=`) all required files in `/etc` (2 dirs and 5 files).

To bind mount the hosts file:

```
BindReadOnlyPaths=/etc/hosts
```

(add openssl, ca-certificates and nameservices to ;))

No need for any scripts to set up the environment, containerization, namespaces, sandboxing, MAC/IPS is possible using `systemd.exec`.